# Is there a tool to check database integrity in Django?

Tags: mysql, database, django, integrity

The MySQL database powering our Django site has developed some integrity problems; e.g. foreign keys that refer to nonexistent rows. I won't go into how we got into this mess, but I'm now looking at how to fix it.

Basically, **I'm looking for a script that scans all models in the Django site, and checks whether all foreign keys and other constraints are correct**. Hopefully, the number of problems will be small enough so they can be fixed by hand.

I could code this up myself but I'm hoping that somebody here has a better idea.

I found [django-check-constraints](https://github.com/theju/django-check-constraints) but it doesn't quite fit the bill: right now, I don't need something to prevent these problems, but to find them so they can be fixed manually before taking other steps.

Other constraints:

- Django **1.1.1** and upgrading has been determined to break things
- MySQL 5.0.51 (Debian Lenny), currently with **MyISAM** tables
- Python 2.5, might be upgradable but I'd rather not right now

(Later, we will convert to InnoDB for proper transaction support, and maybe foreign key constraints on the database level, to prevent similar problems in the future. But that's not the topic of this question.)

Comment: You did not mention just using PostGreSQL, MySQL is mandatory ?

Comment: Not mandatory, no. We'll definitely consider PostgreSQL later, but changing the DBMS is a bit too risky at the moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I whipped up something myself. The management script below should be saved in `myapp/management/commands/checkdb.py`. Make sure that intermediate directories have an `__init__.py` file.

Usage: `./manage.py checkdb` for a full check; use `--exclude app.Model` or `-e app.Model` to exclude the model `Model` in the app `app`.

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db import models
from optparse import make_option
from lib.progress import with_progress_meter

def model_name(model):
    return '%s.%s' % (model._meta.app_label, model._meta.object_name)

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '[-e|--exclude app_name.ModelName]'
    help = 'Checks constraints in the database and reports violations on stdout'

    option_list = NoArgsCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('-e', '--exclude', action='append', type='string', dest='exclude'),
    )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # TODO once we're on Django 1.2, write to self.stdout and self.stderr instead of plain print

        exclude = options.get('exclude', None) or []

        failed_instance_count = 0
        failed_model_count = 0
        for app in models.get_apps():
            for model in models.get_models(app):
                if model_name(model) in exclude:
                    print 'Skipping model %s' % model_name(model)
                    continue
                fail_count = self.check_model(app, model)
                if fail_count > 0:
                    failed_model_count += 1
                    failed_instance_count += fail_count
        print 'Detected %d errors in %d models' % (failed_instance_count, failed_model_count)

    def check_model(self, app, model):
        meta = model._meta
        if meta.proxy:
            print 'WARNING: proxy models not currently supported; ignored'
            return

        # Define all the checks we can do; they return True if they are ok,
        # False if not (and print a message to stdout)
        def check_foreign_key(model, field):
            foreign_model = field.related.parent_model
            def check_instance(instance):
                try:
                    # name: name of the attribute containing the model instance (e.g. 'user')
                    # attname: name of the attribute containing the id (e.g. 'user_id')
                    getattr(instance, field.name)
                    return True
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    print '%s with pk %s refers via field %s to nonexistent %s with pk %s' % \
                        (model_name(model), str(instance.pk), field.name, model_name(foreign_model), getattr(instance, field.attname))
            return check_instance

        # Make a list of checks to run on each model instance
        checks = []
        for field in meta.local_fields + meta.local_many_to_many + meta.virtual_fields:
            if isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey):
                checks.append(check_foreign_key(model, field))

        # Run all checks
        fail_count = 0
        if checks:
            for instance in with_progress_meter(model.objects.all(), model.objects.count(), 'Checking model %s ...' % model_name(model)):
                for check in checks:
                    if not check(instance):
                        fail_count += 1
        return fail_count
```

I'm making this a community wiki because I welcome any and all improvements to my code!

Comment: This looks great.  You should contact the Django core developers and ask them if they would consider something like this in Django itself. I think it's a huge missing feature.

Comment: where does one find lib.progress with_progress_meter? CHeers

Answer (score 2):

Thomas' answer is great but is now a bit out of date.
I have updated it [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/racitup/a584ed2dc4583d61750f08e419ea26c8) to support Django 1.8+.